# How can I remove Windows and upgrade Wubi install to a full install without a CD or USB stick?

Tags: windows, wubi, uninstall

I have Windows XP with Wubi installed.  Now I want to remove Windows XP and upgrade the Wubi install to a full installation.  How can I do that without a USB stick or a CD?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to install ubuntu no cd/usb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/how-to-install-ubuntu-no-cd-usb)

Comment: [Here is some][1] answer to your problem...


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/how-to-install-ubuntu-no-cd-usb

Comment: This might help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354

Comment: If the suggested duplicate doesn't answer your question, perhaps you should look at a series of questions 1)How do I shrink my windows partition, 2)How do I migrate wubi to a full install, and 3)How do I delete my Windows partitions and expand my linux ones.  I, for one, am a fan of atomic knowledge/questions.  Each of these is a piece of atomic knowledge that would make this solution possible.

Comment: The file system maneuver needed to do this is non-trivial.  I would suggest creating a backup and then fix the file system and restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove Windows XP and **upgrade** the Wubi install to a full installation.

Which means you want to keep all your installed applications and settings of Wubi install of Ubuntu in full installation, and I'm afraid its not possible, since Wubi installation within Windows creates a virtual filesystem in a single `.disk` (not sure of this extension) file in Ubuntu's installation folder within Windows, which will be of the size that you chose from the installer during Wubi installation, while full installation involves having a dedicated partition (of type `EXT4` or `btrfs`) specifically for Ubuntu.

You can still keep application **settings** of existing Ubuntu installation by copying every file and folder from your `home` directory and pasting it back to same place in new installation (only recommended if version of Ubuntu is same in both old and new installation). Also, you may want to look into your /etc directory and save the configurations of certain software packages.

Hence, if you want to completely drop your Windows XP and use Ubuntu full-time then, a clean install is much viable option for you. You can get a complete PDF guide on installing and using Ubuntu 12.04 [here](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) (includes screenshots and dead simple to understand).