# Windows 8 Install No Disc/USB

Tags: installation, windows-8

I absolutely abhor Windows 8.
I wanted to install Ubuntu, so I downloaded it and it took me to a bundle of folders. I went back to read the specific instructions for the download, and the first section implies that I will either be using a USB or disc. My computer doesn't have a disc drive and I don't own a USB.
I Googled how to download it without using a disc or USB, and it directs me to a video how to do it on Windows 7.

Is it impossible for me to download Ubuntu then? I want it to replace windows 8, not "dual boot" with it. The computer is new and has nothing on it, I will not be losing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive). It is based on Windows 7, but is applicable to Windows 8 too.

Comment: It really isn't. 
The first (main) answer on that question made absolutely zero sense to me, so I went to the next which just told me to install Wubi. I did, I've installed it and uninstalled it and when I boot my computer it always says the start up failed because I don't have the installation disc.

Comment: Which answer did you follow?

Comment: The answer directly beneath the top one- it simply said to install Wubi. I did, doesn't work.

Comment: The other answers speak of using a flash drive (which I don't have,) or seem to imply that I already have knowledge on the subject. I have no idea what a partition is, and googling for a meaning gave me nothing that made sense in this context.