# Trouble Installing ubuntu on old machine

Tags: system-installation, bios

Trying to install ubuntu onto a machine currently running Windows xp.

The machine does not have a dvd reader and I can't seem to boot from a usb. Any other options?

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive

Comment: @Tim Heidt install ubuntu without dvd drive or USB http://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how