# Re-install Ubuntu on Ubuntu without CD - USB

Tags: system-installation, format, reset

Is that possible to re-install Ubuntu 14.04 on Ubuntu 14.04 without using any cd, dvd or usb? I have only Ubuntu 14.04 on my pc. I have been messing around with this OS as I am new to it. Now I want all the applications, packages, files and configurations.

I found doing this on windows with "wubi" but I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 that is why I am not sure if it works for my situation as well.

Thanks in advance.

---

Does mounting ubuntu .iso file on a virtual driver solve my problem? I mean, can I re-install using a virtual driver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is like a restore feature? If so, you'd have to make a back up first, so that you have a restore point, and then you can use that to "start over".

You can find these settings in System Settings > > System > Backups

Comment: Yes that would probably work if I had a backup :( Yet I don't. Can I re-install by downloading Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu webpage and somehow execute that setup file?

Comment: Then I think that unfortunately, you will only be able to re-install Ubuntu by using the CD or USB drive. If you're having problems with Ubuntu, you could try resetting your settings to the defaults.  This is probably your best bet:
[link](https://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/how-to-reset-ubuntugnome-settings-to-defaults-without-re-installing/)

EDIT: I would also like to highly recommend that you backup any and all files that you do not wish to lose before attempting any sort of reset/re-installation.

Comment: I have nothing to backup. It's been less than a week since I installed Ubuntu. I just tried playonlinux, wine stuff and then wanted to get rid off them but now I have lots of files that i don't actually want. Thanks for the help. I think I'll go with usb drive. Have a nice day.