# Installing ubuntu without usb or cd

Tags: system-installation, dell

I do not have a flash drive or a CD that I can burn, what are some other ways that I could install Ubuntu on my computer (dell latitude d620)?

Comment: you can use do a  PXE Boot but you need another computer

Comment: You may be better off waiting until you're in a condition where you can use a DVD or USB drive. PXE boot, like @Neil suggested, is a possibility, but it's tricky and (like he said) needs another computer to work.

Comment: If you have a running linux system already on the computer, you can chroot into and build ubuntu that way, there are tutorials on how to do this for Kali linux and arch linux as well. Also, you can actually transfer the hard drive to another computer, install ubuntu, switch the hard drive back and it should boot up fine.

Comment: If you have GRUB bootloader installed or can install it from Windows, you can set it up to boot directly from the Ubuntu installation iso image located somewhere on the HDD. @cl-netbox can tell you how this works, I'll call him...

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a running Ubuntu system ... You can add the Ubuntu install ISO file to the GRUB boot menu and install Ubuntu without having to create an installation media (DVD or USB drive).

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install gksu  

gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Insert the following into the file :

```
menuentry "ubuntu install media" {  
set isofile="/…/XXX.iso"  
loopback loop (hdX,XX)$isofile  
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject toram
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Note : ... =  ISO file path | X = disk | XX = partition | XXX = ISO file name )

Save the file and execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot - choose the new entry from the GRUB boot menu and proceed installation as usual.

You will find some alternatives here -> [Is it possible to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive) ?