# How to create a bootable Ubuntu CD for an older laptop

Tags: boot

I downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. I am trying to burn it on a CD. Using CDBurner XP, it says the image file is too big.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1207/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu ISO image is too big for a CD.
You have to burn the image to a DVD.
Alternatively create an USB media.

Reference -> [Install Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to **burn the actual ISO to a DVD** and the other one is to **use a netboot ISO** that you can find [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/14.04/) ; but this version rely on Internet to download installation files.